# Displaying items in wordpress menu on different height

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to display 3 last items in menu on different height. (10px higher)

I am able to style them with:

```
#main-nav li:nth-of-type(n+6){
font-size:12px;
margin-left:30px;
}
```

but for some reason:

```
#main-nav li:nth-of-type(n+6){
margin-top:-10px; 
}
```

does not work.

Any ideas how to achieve that result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working, it is just the parent container that is not letting you see the effects.

Try changing `float:right` on your `#main-nav` to `display:flex` instead.

```
#main-nav {
    /*float: right;*/
    display: flex;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I usually try to avoid using `float` at all in my CSS as they aren't really meant for layout.